# How do I do t test in pyspark on jupyter notebook

Tags: pyspark

I don't know the codes for t-test on pyspark by using jupyter notebook 
Please help me with this question

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the documentation. Here is the link to the page:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/mllib-statistics.html#hypothesis-testing

Let me know if it doesn't make sense.